# Spring Cloud Gateway: why route uri property ignored?

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-gateway

I have only this route conf

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=x-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri=http://localhost:5555/x-service/v1/private/files
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/v1/private/files
```

but app redirects to `/v1/private/files`.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK spring-cloud-gateway `Route` builder takes into account only hostname and port passed to `UriSpec.uri(String uri)`, so only `http://localhost:5555` matters at this point.

So you need to **rewrite your path**, using `RewritePath` gateway filter, like this:

```
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].filters[0]=RewritePath=/v1/private/files, /x-service/v1/private/files
```

First argument is the original path, second - a replacer.
RegEx also can be used there.

Take a look at [spring-cloud-gateway reference docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/docs/current/reference/html/#the-rewritepath-gatewayfilter-factory) for details.
Also I suggest reading [this article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-url-rewriting).